# how to change backbutton color iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, back-button

I've been developed an app for iOS7 which has this design

[image]

As you can see there's a blue arrow for all my BackButton (using UINavigationController and segues), I want to make them red, this is my code:

```
[UIBarButtonItem   appearance]setTintColor:(UIColorFromRGB(toolbarTintColor))];
[[UIBarButtonItem  appearance]setTitleTextAttributes:textAtributesDictionaryNavBarButtons forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

but results only applies to all other buttons, any help I'll appreciate

thanks in advance for the support

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The tint color property of a navigation bar determines the color of the text of its bar button items in iOS 7.  The code you are looking for is something like this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

and, of course, replacing `[UIColor redColor]` with whatever color you want.

Comment: the tintColor property does not have UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR so I think this solution may be unreliable. Enrico Susatyo's answer seems like the correct one.

Comment: Somehow this works in iOS 8 (8.1) for me but not iOS 7. Only the text color changes, not the <
Used to work in iOS 7 before. Hmm..

Answer (score 12):

Put this code in your App Delegate:

**Objective-C**

```
[self.window setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

**Swift**

```
self.window?.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Comment: This is a better answer since it suggests to customize the navigation text in AppDelegate.m.

Comment: But I don't want to change the text color of my Tab Bar

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to change the tint colour in the whole app and just want to do it on one navigation bar, do this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want the swift version.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Also, if you want to apply this style to all your navigation view controllers. Put that code in your application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in your AppDelegate

Answer (score 1):

Swift:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
```

Answer (score 1):

- If you're using storyboard, then you've to add a user defined attribute for keyPath 'tintColor' under the class inspector pane.
- Because the static tintColor property was removed in latest version of Interface builder. [image: click '+', add tintColor in KeyPath, set the Type color and add your color.]

Answer (score 1):

You can set it in IB directly:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   //set back button color
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor redColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //set back button arrow color
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```